# Can't get Ubuntu boot from Windows 7 boot loader

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, multi-boot

I have a HP Envy Laptop which was shipped with Win 8. Since I am not very comfortable with Win 8, I wanted to install the Win 7 + Ubuntu 14 combination with dual boot option. I have successfully installed Windows 7. After installing Win 7, I installed Ubuntu on the other hard drive (laptop has 2 hard drives).

Previously I had a laptop with only 1 hard drive, and when I installed Win7+Ubuntu on the same hard drive, I was able to add Ubuntu in the Windows boot loader using EasyBCD and got both of them booting successfully. But now, even if I am adding Ubuntu to Windows boot loader using EasyBCD, I couldn't get it work (Tried both GRUB Legacy and GRUB 2 while adding boot records from EasyBCD).

This is the message I am getting when I select Ubuntu from the boot screen.

```
Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause. To fix the problem:

1. Insert your Windows installation disc and restart your computer
2. Choose your language settings, and then click "Next."
3. Click "Repair your computer."
If you do not have this disc, contact your system administrator or computer manufacturer for assistance.
File: \NST\nst_linux.mbr
Status: 0xc000000f
Info: The selected entry could not be loaded because the application is missing or corrupt.
```

I actually have searched SU and web before posting this question, but couldn't find a solution. I would appreciate any help or suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I believe control is passing to the MBR of the second disk and the disk used to boot Windows sometime in the past.  When you installed Ubuntu it probably replaced the MBR on your first disk and you had to fix it to get back to Windows, didn't you?  If not, you may have selected to make just the partition bootable, but then one of the EasyBCD options should have worked.

Basically, you need to get the MBR and grub install all sorted out on the second drive. EasyBCD doesn't actually mess with the Linux partition itself. Fixing the MBR can be done with a dd copy of a new one onto the first sector of the disk.